# Does explode(implode()) make any sense in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I found this piece of code in the [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/):

```
$os_packages_to_install = explode(' ', implode(' ', $os_packages_to_install));
```

I've seen it before and I don't see it's point. What does it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will return an array but the difference with `$os_packages_to_install` is that if a value of `$os_packages_to_install` contains a space, it will also be splitted.

so:

```
["hjk jklj","jmmj","hl mh","hlm"]
```

implode gives:

```
"hjk jklj jmmj hl mh hlm
```

explode again will give:

```
["hjk","jklj","jmmj","hl","mh","hlm"]
```

Comment: And the array will be re-indexed, as others pointed out below.

Answer (score 6):

A google search of the line came up with this:

> Rebuild the array index since some
>   OS package XML tags provide multiple
>   package names in a single string

Basically, it's because the original array might look like this:

```
$os_packages_to_install = array(
  'package1',
  'package2 package3'
);
```

When it needs to look like this:

```
$os_packages_to_install = array(
  'package1',
  'package2',
  'package3'
);
```

Source: http://www.phorogit.com/index.php?p=phoronix-test-suite.git&dl=plain&h=7c5f0c0cf91dc61c1f220b0871040d4441836436.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if strings in array `$os_packages_to_install` has whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

it may, if input array is associative:

```
$os_packages_to_install = array('key'=>'val1','val2','val3');
var_dump($os_packages_to_install);
var_dump(explode(' ', implode(' ', $os_packages_to_install)));
```

output is:

```
array(3) { ["key"]=> string(4) "val1" [0]=> string(4) "val2" [1]=> string(4) "val3" }
array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "val1" [1]=> string(4) "val2" [2]=> string(4) "val3" }
```

Answer (score 0):

if string contains whitespace like 
$str[0] = "abcd bce";
$str[1] = "bcde sdf";
and if one executes your command then .

it will be splitted in array with 4 records rather then splitting in 2.